# multiple google maps in activity and fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

In my app I have a main activity containning a map fragment.
The rest of the app is built with fragment.
I have one fragment which requires another map.
For some odd reason, the layout I leave for the map (in the fragment layout) is transparent, and I am able to see the map of the main activity, and not the desired map.
Has anyone come accross this issue, and is able to help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

make the background parent layout of fragment xml as white and also set clickable=true for the same parent